# How to use Application.Current.Properties or some other Global variable

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class called `RandomGen` which generates random variables when called like so:

```
RandomGen u = new RandomGen();
            int QRNOne = u.QuestionRandNo(n);
            n++;
```

How  do I then set `QRNOne` as a global variable to be accessed later? Also, can I do this from within the class, and have it create this variable? (I realise there is no "real" global variable in C# WPF, but you ought to understand what I'm referring to.)

Comment: A static field in a static class is a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read up on [static class members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

I'm sure you know that global variables are best avoided if possible, but if you really need a static member variable then you would do something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static int QRNOne {get; private set;}

    public void GenerateRandom(){ ... ; QRNOne = ...;  }
}
```

And then refer to that variable from elsewhere as

```
public void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    int qr = MyClass.QRNone;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, but what sort of thing should I be putting in here: { ... ; QRNOne = ...;  } 
As in what should the "..." be. I really am a beginner.

Comment: Just put the code you have above. RandomGen u = new RandomGen();
            QRNOne = u.QuestionRandNo(n);
            n++;

Comment: Thanks Phil. I didn't quite get it working, I found another way, but I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a static, Singleton style class with properties tor the values you want to use? This should then have global visibilty with sufficient structure and encapsulation.